# How thisarg value return undefined while in second iteration

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm getting undefined value in thisarg element for second iteration in forEach loop.

```
var array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

array1.forEach(function(element, index) {

  console.log(element === this[index]);

  console.log(this[index]);

}, array1[1]);
```

Expected output: 
false
"b"
true
"b"
false
"b"

Actually I'm getting this in output:

false
"b"
false
undefined
false
undefined

Comment: What do you think "this" is in this context?

Comment: since `this === array[1] === "b"` then `this[0] === "b"[0] === 'b'` ... `this[1] === "b"[1] === undefined` - where's the mystery?

Comment: Thanks for your time @zero298. Now I got how it works.

Comment: Thank for your time @JaromandaX. Now I got how it works.
var array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

array1.forEach(function(element, index) {

  console.log(element === String(this));

  console.log(String(this));

}, array1[1]);

This getting expected values

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you think that the `this` in your function is the array, but from your results, it appears to be the current element.

If you need to access the array, then it is passed as a third argument.

```
array1.forEach(function(element, index arr) { });
```

Comment: @RArunkumar Comments are intended for clarification and constructive criticism. Instead of posting 'thanks', you can upvote or accept the post. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers